# JS into Rails Asset Pipeline

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, bower

My manifest for Rails Asset Pipeline looks like this:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs

//= jquery-backstretch/jquery.backstretch.js
```

I have my vendor directory as follows:

```
vendor
  assets
    components
      jquery-backstretch
        jquery.backstretch.js
```

But it's not importing the backstretch.js file at all as I get an error in my page.

I have components added to the asset path as follows:

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("vendor", "assets", "components")
```

Any ideas on how I can get that js file to be used?

Comment: Are you attempting to include the backstretch js directly in your pages, or are you expecting it as part of your application.js?

Comment: I was expecting it as part of application.js

Comment: I think you need a `require` before jquery-backstretch, and just `//= require jquery-backstretch` should work.

Comment: OMG. *embarassed* Why is it the smallest things I miss. Thanks for solving it. Been bugging me all this evening and all last evening! Why was I so silly as to not spot that!!!???

Comment: It took me hours to figure out that my app died one time because I removed jquery-ujs and it is necessary for CSRF protection :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my comment above:

`require` is needed in front of `jquery-backstretch`.